# UNIX syntax for grep command

Tags: unix

For the file `james`, running this command:

```
cat james | grep I'm,
```

I get:

```
>
>
>
.
.
```

probably because of the '

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote your string:

```
grep "I'm," james
```

(you can skip the `cat` part too)

Comment: classic grep syntax is: "grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]" so after the pattern, everything is a file.  ex. `grep "I'm," james blam kapow`  will search the files named "james", "blam", and "kapow"